# Render a page and send Json with express and handlebars

Tags: node.js, json, handlebars.js

I have a webpage with a form. On click of the button My webserver has to take all the stored chat of a profile in an sql db and it has to send this chat in a webpage. I used json messages and I can assure that the logic is working. 
Now I have to:

1. Render the html webpage
2. Send the json message to this html webpage so that it could display it in a proper way (not flat)

How can I do that? I am using express and handlebars.
Here is my code:

```
router.get('/chatlist', ensureAuthenticated, (req,res)=>{
    let mittente = req.user.id;
    findUsersChat(mittente)
    .then(Chats=>{
        getChatData(Chats,mittente).then(ChatList=>{
            console.log("Lista2: " +ChatList);
            var obj=JSON.parse(ChatList);
            res.render('chatlist');
//            res.render('chatlist', {obj});
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))

    });

})
```

chatlist.handlebars

```
<section id="gigs" class="container">
    <h1>Chats Available</h1>

        {{#each obj}}
        <h1>{{Nome}}</h1>
        <div class="form-group">
          <form method="POST" action="/users/chat">  
            <p>Utente numero : {{@index}}</p>
            <label for="name" value={{Nome}}>{{Nome}}</label>

          </form>

        </div>
        {{/each}}
  </section>
```